# How to use overloaded static operators

Tags: f#, operator-overloading, static-methods, type-inference

I'm writing a tiny matrix library (mostly wrapper methods) in F#, and have a problem regarding overloading of static operator methods, with F# picking an overload which I did not intend it to.

I have a module where I've defined the right-multiplication of a matrix with a vector:

```
[<AutoOpen>]
module MatrixOps =

let (*) (matrix : IMatrix) (vector : IVector) =
    (...)
```

This lets me write things like e.g. A * v where A is an IMatrix and v is an IVector. However, I now add the following line below the let-binding above:

```
let z = 1.0 * 2.0
```

and then, the F# compiler identifies this as an error. Hovering over "1.0", I get: "The type 'float' is not compatible with the type 'IMatrix", and similarly, hovering over "2.0", I get: "The type 'float' is not compatible with the type 'IVector'". What's going on here seems to be that the F# compiler fails to apply the multiplication operator for floats and instead applies the operator for IMatrix and IVector. If I instead write

```
let z = (1.0 : float) * (2.0 : float)
```

the problem persists, so adding explicit type annotions doesn't help. How can I ensure that F# picks the floating multiplication operator instead of the IMatrix / IVector operator I defined above?

Comment: You want to make the overload a static member of the type of one of the objects, then it works like you want

Comment: Alright. But is there another way? If the multiplication method is on either the IMatrix or IVector interface, then I'll have introduced an unwanted dependency.

Comment: It's not a dependency.  You need the types anyway

Comment: Well, if I put a static method IMatrix * IVector -> IVector on e.g. the IMatrix interface, then IMatrix depends on IVector. Yes, I need the types anyway, but I don't need the types to depend on each other. Right now, neither IMatrix or IVector depends on the other, and I prefer it that way.

Comment: @AlexanderSokol see the Note below my answer. Another advantage if you design your overloads the way I'm suggesting is that they will not depend on each other.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

F# doesn't allow you to define overloads just by adding let bound functions.

F# support standard .NET instance or static member overloads, so in this case you need to add a static member:

```
type Matrix =
  static member (*) (matrix : Matrix) (vector : IVector) = ..
```

NOTE: I advise you against such design with overloads between matrices and vectors. If you continue defining overloads this way, I mean between mixed types, overload resolution may become ambiguous.

It's better to define the overload only between Matrices and then another set between Vectors. Then you can define a function like `asMatrix` that allows you to wrap a vector in a Matrix and then multiply matrices.

Comment: I think this us a typo: _It's better to define the overload between Matrices and Vectors_.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin kind-of, now that you mention I notice it's not clear. I will rephrase it. Thanks !

Comment: Thanks. I think your comment about asMatrix is sound. I do have some follow-up questions. If I (literally) do the above, Matrix will depend on IVector. I'd rather not couple the two. A potential way to avoid coupling would be to define a "static extension method on the IMatrix interface" , but interfaces can't have static methods. Perhaps the only way to make this work is by introducing a dependency?

Comment: @AlexanderSokol when you say 'if I literally do the above' what do you mean? My code sample or my advice?

Comment: Oh, I meant the code, i.e. if I actually put the static member in the Matrix class.

Comment: @Gustavo well, it's not a problem at present. But it seems like a code smell to me. What if I one day need Vector to depend on Matrix? And in any case, from a principal standpoint, the two concepts do not depend on each other. So it's only a problem in the sense of preferring fewer dependencies to more.

Comment: @AlexanderSokol Dependencies are normal. We always depend on code, we depend on FSharpCore types which at the same time depend on the .NET primitive types and so on. Anyway if you really want to follow that way and at the same time avoid the dependencies there is a way to achieve that by using for example a jagged array as intermediate representation and then use interfaces or static member constraints to convert from and to arrays.